# Ubuntu runs normally if I enter the second option in Grub menu. Doesn't work with the default option

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, kernel

If I go to my Ubuntu 22.10 Grub Menu I have 4 options:

Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-28-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-28-generic (recovery)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-58-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-58-generic (recovery)

If I start Ubuntu using the default (first one), my graphic card, and wireless card, bluetooth and other drivers don't start. I am not sure what happened to cause this error but I expect it's the latest dis-upgrade.

Anyway, if I enter using Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-58-generic, everything loads normally and the system runs smoothly.

My questions:

1. What's the difference between the two options
   Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-28-generic
   Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-58-generic

and how can I remove Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-28-generic and make Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-58-generic the default one since it's the one that's working properly?

Comment: Boot into `5.15.0-58-generic` and run `dkms status`.  If the drivers in question are not listed, then you will need to install them again into the new kernel.  DKMS allows for certain drivers that are not in the kernel to be loaded when a new Kernel update is pushed to the system as the source files will be placed in a location for when the new Kernel update installs it will install those drivers as well.  But the driver will have to be converted over to DKMS to carry over into new Kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Please, remove 5.19 kernel with the commands

```
sudo apt remove linux-image-5.19.0-28-generic linux-headers-5.19.0-28-generic linux-modules-5.19.0-28-generic
```

Please, reboot the computer. After that, there will be only 5.15 kernel in the grub list.

5.19 and 5.15 are different Linux kernels, and you have problems with 5.19.